# Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Shared.dll'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

I am working on a xamarin forms application which targets android and ios. the app works fine when running both android and ios, but i also wanted to add support for UWP. I added a new project which targets windows and i have added all the packages and dependencies and all that was required, but i keep getting this error when i try to run the app.

> Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Shared.dll'

and

> Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Shared, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

I have no idea why i am getting this error, so if anyone has any information about this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/)?

Comment: Yes, that was the guide I used to add a windows project to my solution.

Comment: Could you share a simple sample that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: I fixed the issue. it was a problem with one of classes in a different project in the solution. I don't really know what caused the issue, but I got it to work.

Comment: Ok, I think you could post your answer here. And accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. it was a problem with one of the classes in a different project in the solution. I don't really know what caused the issue, but I got it to work by adding the class to a different part of the solution.